# PivotTable allows Skill filter and shows distribution of each Skill level

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have an Excel sheet set up basically with the first two columns as a person's name and their ID. Then the rest of the columns are title of a skill. The values of the table are basically the skill levels (0-4). So it looks like:

```
| Name   | ID | Skill 1 | Skill 2|  
| Jane   | 01 | 3       | 4      |
```

I was wondering how I can use pivot tables to make it so that I have a column where I can I select in the dropdown the "Skill" and in that column would be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 then the column next to it shows the Count of how many people put `0` for that skill etc.

Right now I have it like that but only one skill and if I wanted to change to a different skill, I have to manually change the pivot table row label.  I was hoping to just change it within the pivot table itself. 
 I could rearrange the data to make this work but I'm having trouble conceptualizing how the data should be organized for this.

Is this doable in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Normally for pivot tables you want the data in a format more like this

```
Name  ID  Skill#  Skill Value
Jane  01    1      3
Jane  01    2      4
```

Then you would be able to show what you want in the pivot table.  You could then use report filters or column labels (with filters) to only show skill# 1 or skill#2.